# Android WebView: handling orientation changes

Tags: android, webview, orientation

The issue is the performance following rotation. The WebView has to reload the page, which can be a bit tedious.

What's the best way of handling an orientation change without reloading the page from source each time?

Comment: By "reloading from source" do you mean it's downloading the page again, or just re-rendering it?

Comment: The solution referenced by Blackhex solved my problem.

Comment: I wonder what the hell's so special about my app that none of these answers work...

Answer (score 91):

If you do not want the WebView to reload on orientation changes simply override onConfigurationChanged in your Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

And set the android:configChanges attribute in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="..."
          android:label="@string/appName"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

for more info see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: I tested but found do not work, set configChanges attribute like below will work.
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: doing that is in fact discouraged, as has been mentioned many times before

Comment: Matthias: This is not really true - see Javadoc for WebView.

Comment: Two things to note about this solution: 1) If you have an abstract Activity with a WebView, the `configChanges` attribute gets added to the subclass Activity 2) If your app depends on multiple projects, the `configChanges` attribute gets added to the manifest of the one at the top of the dependency tree (which may not be the project containing the Activity class).

Comment: +1 for android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". I had android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" but was missing the screenSize flag. It now works like a charm!

Comment: orientation|screenSize with Android 3.2 (API level 13)

Comment: Hmmm... I get "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|screenSize')."

Comment: Works perfect for me when I changed it to android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"

Comment: Android is a platform where things that don't work are encouraged and things thad DO work are discouraged.

Comment: Such `onConfigurationChanged` method override is useless.

Comment: Working on android 4.1

Comment: Works on Android Oreo.

Comment: Do you know how to make when orientation changes make full screen for when it is in landscape make full video of youtube while playing ?

Answer (score 72):

Edit: This method no longer works as stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState(android.os.Bundle))

---

Original answer:

This can be handled by overrwriting `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` in your activity and calling `saveState` from the webview:

```
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      webView.saveState(outState);
   }
```

Then recover this in your onCreate after the webview has been re-inflated of course:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.blah);
   if (savedInstanceState != null)
      ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on orientation change — blank screen is shown. saveState\restoreState methods are called but it doesn't help.

Comment: Here is onCreate code snippet: setContentView(R.layout.webview);
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   mWebView.setWebViewClient(new SimpleWebViewClient());
   mWebView.loadUrl(Consts.URL_AUTHORIZATION_OAUTH);
  } else {
   mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
  }

Comment: From the documentation of saveState: _Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files..._

Comment: "Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView" - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion on what to do now that "this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView" in order to prevent a WebView form reloading?

Answer (score 26):

The best answer to this is following Android documentation found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)
Basically this will prevent Webview from reloading:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|uiMode"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Edit(1/4/2020): You don't need this optional code, the manifest attribute is all you need, leaving optional code here to keep answer complete.

**Optionally**, you can fix anomalies (if any) by overriding `onConfigurationChanged` in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the onConfigurationChanged() method I am pretty sure, just the additional attribute in the Manifest.  My guess is that native support for this was provided by the WebView, and this is why this answer is now the best one (because this didn't work when the question was originally asked)

Comment: I approve  @Booger you dont need to override the onConfigurationChanged() method.All you need is add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest.xml file.

Comment: @Booger in  answer also saying, optional that code, not mandatory.

Comment: What should I do if I use webview in Fragment?

Answer (score 6):

I've tried using **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance** (returning the *WebView*), then getting it back with **getLastNonConfigurationInstance** during **onCreate** and re-assigning it.

Doesn't seem to work just yet. I can't help but think I'm really close though! So far, I just get a blank/white-background *WebView* instead. Posting here in the hopes that someone can help push this one past the finish line.

Maybe I shouldn't be passing the *WebView*. Perhaps an object from within the *WebView*?

The other method I tried - not my favorite - is to set this in the activity:

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

... and then do pretty much nothing here:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // We do nothing here. We're only handling this to keep orientation
  // or keyboard hiding from causing the WebView activity to restart.
}
```

THAT works, but it might not be considered a [best practice](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/11/11/rotational-forces-part-three/#IDComment31451819).

Meanwhile, I also have a single *ImageView* that I want to automagically update depending on the rotation. This turns out to be very easy. Under my `res` folder, I have `drawable-land` and `drawable-port` to hold landscape/portrait variations, then I use `R.drawable.myimagename` for the *ImageView*'s source and Android "does the right thing" - yay!

... except when you watch for config changes, then it doesn't. :(

So I'm at odds. Use **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance** and the *ImageView* rotation works, but *WebView* persistence doesn't ... or use **onConfigurationChanged** and the *WebView* stays stable, but the *ImageView* doesn't update. What to do?

One last note: In my case, forcing orientation isn't an acceptable compromise. We really do want to gracefully support rotation. Kinda like how the Android Browser app does! ;)

Comment: You shouldn't return any Views from onRetainNonConfigurationInstance. The views are attached to the Activity Context so if you save the view you carry over all that baggage every time there is an orientation change. The view is "leaked". (See last paragraph here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

The best practice for onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is to save the data that the view needs, not the view itself.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate this is a little late, however this is the answer that I used when developing my solution:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WebClient"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" <--- "screenSize" important
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_client" >
    </activity>
```

WebClient.java

```
public class WebClient extends Activity {

    protected FrameLayout webViewPlaceholder;
    protected WebView webView;

    private String WEBCLIENT_URL;
    private String WEBCLIENT_TITLE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_client);
        initUI();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void initUI(){
        // Retrieve UI elements
        webViewPlaceholder = ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder));

        // Initialize the WebView if necessary
        if (webView == null)
        {
            // Create the webview
            webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

            // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
            webView.setWebViewClient(new SetWebClient());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

            // Load a page
            webView.loadUrl(WEBCLIENT_URL);
        }

        // Attach the WebView to its placeholder
        webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
    }

    private class SetWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        if (webView != null){
            // Remove the WebView from the old placeholder
            webViewPlaceholder.removeView(webView);
        }

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Load the layout resource for the new configuration
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_client);

        // Reinitialize the UI
        initUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the state of the WebView
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the state of the WebView
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One compromise is to avoid rotation.
Add this to fix the activity for Portrait orientation only.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: This actually works in many cases and is the solution I have decided to implement :-)

Comment: hehe, this is a requirement change

Answer (score 3):

Best way to handle orientation changes and Preventing WebView reload on Rotate.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

With that in mind, to prevent onCreate() from being called every time you change orientation, you would have to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to the AndroidManifest.`

or just ..

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write the following code lines in your Manifest file - nothing else. It really works:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
  android:label="@string/application_name">
```

Answer (score 2):

It is 2015, and many people are looking for a solution that still workds on Jellybean, KK and Lollipop phones.
After *much* struggling I found a way to preserve the webview intact after you change orientation.
My strategy is basically to store the webview in a separate static variable in another class. Then, if rotation occurs, I dettach the webview from the activity, wait for the orientation to finish, and reattach the webview back to the activity.
For example... first put this on your MANIFEST (keyboardHidden and keyboard are optional):

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.myapp.abc.app">

    <activity
            android:name=".myRotatingActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
```

In a SEPARATE APPLICATION CLASS, put:

```
     public class app extends Application {
            public static WebView webview;
            public static FrameLayout webviewPlaceholder;//will hold the webview

         @Override
               public void onCreate() {
                   super.onCreate();
    //dont forget to put this on the manifest in order for this onCreate method to fire when the app starts: android:name="com.myapp.abc.app"
                   setFirstLaunch("true");
           }

       public static String isFirstLaunch(Context appContext, String s) {
           try {
          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
          return prefs.getString("booting", "false");
          }catch (Exception e) {
             return "false";
          }
        }

    public static void setFirstLaunch(Context aContext,String s) {
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(aContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("booting", s);
            editor.commit();
           }
        }
```

In the ACTIVITY put:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(app.isFirstLaunch.equals("true"))) {
            app.setFirstLaunch("false");
            app.webview = new WebView(thisActivity);
            initWebUI("www.mypage.url");
        }
}
@Override
    public  void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        restoreWebview();
    }

public void restoreWebview(){
        app.webviewPlaceholder = (FrameLayout)thisActivity.findViewById(R.id.webviewplaceholder);
        if(app.webviewPlaceholder.getParent()!=null&&((ViewGroup)app.webview.getParent())!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup) app.webview.getParent()).removeView(app.webview);
        }
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        app.webview.setLayoutParams(params);
        app.webviewPlaceholder.addView(app.webview);
        app.needToRestoreWebview=false;
    }

protected static void initWebUI(String url){
        if(app.webviewPlaceholder==null);
          app.webviewPlaceholder = (FrameLayout)thisActivity.findViewById(R.id.webviewplaceholder);
        app.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       app.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        app.webview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        app.webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        app.webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        app.webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        app.webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        app.webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        app.webview.loadUrl(url);
        app.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if((app.webview.getParent()!=null)){//&&(app.getBooting(thisActivity).equals("true"))) {
            ((ViewGroup) app.webview.getParent()).removeView(app.webview);
        }
        app.webviewPlaceholder.addView(app.webview);
    }
```

Finally, the simple XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".myRotatingActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webviewplaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are several things that could be improved in my solution, but I already spent to much time, for example: a shorter way to validate if the Activity has been launched for the very first time instead of using SharedPreferences storage.
This approach preserves you webview intact (afaik),its textboxes, labels, UI, javascript variables, and navigation states that are not reflected by the url.

Comment: Why even bother detaching and reattaching the WebView when it never gets destroyed in the first place since you manually handle configuration changes?

Comment: @Fred Because I want to keep the exact state of the Webview and its contents intact, including cookies, and the state of buttons and checkboxes implemented with HTML5 or JS inside webpage loaded by the webview. The only adjustment I do is resizing.

Comment: Fred meant you don't need to detach/reattach the webview via a static class as you declared configChanges in the manifest. This way, your views and activity don't get destroyed during rotation in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Update: current strategy is to move WebView instance to Application class instead of retained fragment when it's detached and reattach on resume as Josh does.
To prevent Application from closing, you should use foreground service, if you want to retain state when user switches between applications.

<s>If you are using fragments, you can use retain instance of the WebView. 
The web view will be retained as instance member of the class. You should however attach web view in OnCreateView and detach before OnDestroyView to prevent it from destruction with the parent container.</s>

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{  

    public MyFragment(){  setRetainInstance(true); }

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = ....
       LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(...);
       if (webView == null) {
            webView = new WebView(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); 
       }
       ll.removeAllViews();
       ll.addView(webView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

       return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getRetainInstance() && webView.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
           ((ViewGroup) webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    } 
}
```

P.S. Credits go to [kcoppock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985760/241986)

As for 'SaveState()' it no longer works according to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for
>   this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files if
>   restoreState(Bundle) was never called.

Comment: Note that while `setRetainInstance` does retain the Fragment the view (and hence the WebView) still gets destroyed.

Comment: @Fred Can you provide a source for that statement? I have tested this in a small app which has a fragment with setRetainInstance(true) that displays a youtube page and if I change the orientation, the view seems to be retained as the video is not interrupted. Doesn't seem like the webview is getting destroyed.

Comment: @Rai It's was just a misreading, I have edited a bit the answer since then(it still needs some wording fixes). If you are interested in current state of affairs - this method works. However the problem is that android kills application when it's low on memory. I have an important input form where user has to read a message in another application,  so I had to use foreground service with notification to prevent process from being killed. Yet android still destroys activity and hence the retained frame. But the instance of Application class is preserved  - so I move WebView to Application now.

Comment: I also use MutableContextWrapper as base of the WebView, I switch contexts to activities on attach and detach.
Another big problem that Chromium build in zoom controls save reference to old activity, so no zoom in solution with WebView attached to Application instead of Activity. **TL;DR;** if your form is not that important, and you may live with fact that after app switching your process can be killed and webview not restored go with retained frame solution. P.S. also I think that Google employees are far, far from real life problems with all their  widgets-gadgets..

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you should do is adding this code to your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/application_name">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` on your Activity to call `saveState(...)` and `restoreState(...)` on your WebView instance.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found to do this without leaking the previous `Activity` reference and without setting the `configChanges`.. is to use a [MutableContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/MutableContextWrapper.html).

I've implemented this here: https://github.com/slightfoot/android-web-wrapper/blob/48cb3c48c457d889fc16b4e3eba1c9e925f42cfb/WebWrapper/src/com/example/webwrapper/BrowserActivity.java

Comment: does this work reliably without side-effects?  I haven't found much information about this method.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me (I even used the save instance state in `onCreateView` but it wasn't as reliable).

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment
{
    private enum WebViewStateHolder
    {
        INSTANCE;

        private Bundle bundle;

        public void saveWebViewState(WebView webView)
        {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            webView.saveState(bundle);
        }

        public Bundle getBundle()
        {
            return bundle;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.saveWebViewState(myWebView);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); 
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
        if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try
            {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("start.html")));

                String line = null;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Failed reading HTML.", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(br != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        br.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Kappa", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            myWebView
                .loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", stringBuilder.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }
        else
        {
            myWebView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I made a Singleton holder for the state of the WebView. The state is preserved as long as the process of the application exists.

EDIT: The `loadDataWithBaseURL` wasn't necessary, it worked just as well with just

```
    //in onCreate() for Activity, or in onCreateView() for Fragment

    if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/merged.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
    }
```

Although I read this doesn't necessarily work well with cookies.

Comment: Using singleton is problematic, as it assumes you have only one instance that you need to use.

Comment: @androiddeveloper ah. Well, if that's not true in your case, then indeed that is a problem. I only had one WebView instance, so this question didn't even come up for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String url = "https://www.google.ps/";

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        else {
            wv.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            wv.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        wv.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wv.canGoBack())
            wv.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);    
}
```

These methods can be overridden on any activity, it just basically allows you to save and restore values each time an activity is created/destroyed, when the screen orientation changes the activity gets destroyed and recreated in the background, so therefore you could use these methods to temporary store/restore states during the change.

You should have a deeper look into the two following methods and see whether it fits your solution.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

This page solve my problem but I have to make slight change in initial one:

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       webView.saveState(outState);
       }
```

This portion has a slight problem for me this. On the second orientation change the application terminated with null pointer

using this it worked for me:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ){
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview)).saveState(outState);
}
```

Comment: seems to be exactly the same. Why would the second one work while the previous won't?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1. Create a service, inside that service, create your WebView.
2. Start the service from your activity and bind to it.
3. In the `onServiceConnected` method, get the WebView and call the `setContentView` method to render your WebView.

I tested it and it works but not with other WebViews like XWalkView or GeckoView.

Comment: Hi! Could you explain it more? Thank you

Comment: Well, get your webview instance form you Activity and try to put its refrence to a service that is running in background. 
The next time you open that activity, try to get the saved webview first and render it.

Answer (score -1):

I like this solution http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/

According to it we reuse the same instance of WebView. It allows to save navigation history and scroll position on configuration change.

Comment: Link above leads to a page that can't be viewed without installing some 'security plugin'; avoid.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some lines of explanation to your answer?