# Loading existing .html file with android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

I did try samples, demos from Google codes and other resources with `WebView`, but when i try to do it in my own code, it doesn't work for me.

I want to load `myfile.html` which i put in assets folder, and using:

```
private WebView myWebView;

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/myfile.html");
```

On emulator shows error

> The web page at `file:///android_assets/myfile.html` could not be
>   loaded as: The requested file was not found.
>   `/android_assets/myfile.html`

When i put that file to `res/raw/` folder and using:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/myfile.html");
```

then only emulator android 2.2 API level 8 can load the file probably, other older versions show the same error. Am i missing something?

Is there any way of loading an existing .html file in the application package which works on all API versions ?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

ok, that was my very stupid mistake. I post the answer here just in case someone has the same problem.

The correct path for files stored in assets folder is `file:///android_asset/*` (with no "s" for assets folder which i was always thinking it must have a "s").

And, `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");` works under all API levels.

I still not figure out why `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/myfile.html");` works only on API level 8. But it doesn't matter now.

Comment: FWIW I don't think it was a stupid mistake. I made the same mistake now, twice. It's not intuitive! First make a folder called "assets" then refer to it by "android_asset" (no "s")?? It's the platform that's stupid, IMO :P

Comment: to bad `raw` did not work. I would have use for `raw-de`, `raw-fr`and so on. Now I have to do it myself.

Comment: i tried the same way guided by laph but when i put my xml file in the folder mentioned by you myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/myfile.xml");   It gives me error that Make sure internet or path is correct and when i write myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_res/raw/myfile.xml"); it do not give any error but it also shows nothing.Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi Aditya, i believe that error is because your file is .xml. loadUrl suppose to load a .html file. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Is this possible? 
Folder assets contains Javascript and other files, folder res/raw contains HTML files

Comment: This does not seem to work for localized resources as @martin pointed out. Does anyone have a clue where to start? I need to show 3 languages,and have the file-en.html, file-es.html and file-de.html files, all set.

Comment: To use the raw folder use "android_res/raw/". More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171362/753632

Answer (score 20):

If your structure should be like this:

`/assets/html/index.html`

`/assets/scripts/index.js`

`/assets/css/index.css`

Then just do ( [Android WebView: handling orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes/27020832#27020832) )

```
    if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null) { //this works only on single instance of webview, use a map with TAG if you need more
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
    }
```

Make sure you add

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Then just use urls

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zzzz</title>
    <script src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
```

Answer (score 17):

paste your .html file in assets folder of your project folder.
and create an xml file in layout folder with the fol code: 
my.xml:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

add fol code in activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.my);
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html"); //new.html is html file name.
```

Answer (score 6):

Copy and Paste Your .html file in the assets folder of your Project and add below code in your Activity on onCreate().

```
        WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/**YOUR FILE NAME**.html");
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setContentView(view);
```

Comment: it was the tripple slash that got me ///

Answer (score 3):

The **debug compilation** is different from the **release** one, so:

Consider your Project file structure like that [*this case if for a Debug assemble*]:

```
src
  |
  debug
      |
      assets
           |
           index.html
```

You should call **index.html** into your WebView like:

```
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

So forth, for the Release assemble, it should be like:

```
src
  |
  release
        |
        assets
             |
             index.html
```

> The bellow structure also works, **for both compilations** [*debug and release*]:

```
src
  |
  main
     |
     assets
          |
          index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read the html file manually and then use `loadData` or `loadDataWithBaseUrl` methods of WebView to show it.

Comment: Hi Lucho, thanks for your answer. You means that i have to convert my .html file into String, then load it with loadData or loadDataWithBaseUrl method?

Comment: my .html files are quite big to convert to string quickly. Any idea to load it with absolute path?