# Web Page Not Available - Loading local HTML on Android

Tags: java, android, webview

Yo guys, this is bugging me and I can't find a fix for it,

I have a simple activity to launch a WebView and display a HTML file

```
public class HelpViewer extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.help_page_layout);

    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.help_page_webview);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html/");
}}
```

The help_page_layout is your standard WebView resting in a LinearLayout - Not problems there.

The help.html is sitting under the /res/raw/ directory. From what I have see online, there shouldn't be a problem here either.

But when the WebView goes to load, it just tells me that the WebPage was not available because help.html couldn't be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/problem-with-loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview) suggests the file should be in `/assets` rather than `/res/raw`.  You also have a trailing slash on the end of your URL.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, this answer is correct, thank you.