# What's correct path to html pages for loading into WebView?

Tags: android, webview, assets

I know that there are a lot of questions about to load HTMl-pages into WebView.
What am I doing? I just put down the 1.html in assets folder in android-project and use

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///assets/"+selectedItem+".html");
```

where 
    selecteditem

is data from intent. As result I get the message in WebView that:

file:///assets/1.html  was not found.

UPD: sorry, I found the solution. the correct path should be the follow:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+selectedItem+".html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path is `file:///android_asset/1.html`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,but it may work:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
```

Know more about the same type of mistake: [Loading existing .html file with android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/problem-with-loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview/4029605#4029605)