# how to show Rich text file for offline help in android

Tags: android

I want to save a `.rtf` Rich text file with my app as offline help. when the user clicks for offline help, the app will show this text file. I don't want to use pdf help file because it wont be accessible on phone with no pdf viewer.

I would like to use html offline page stored in Assets folder if that is a better approach than the RTF file.

I have seen this [Loading existing .html file with android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview) just looking for the .rtf file answer now

Comment: I think it's better to use html file as offline help. you can use it via `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks @MajidDaeiNejad I will go for this solution.

Comment: your welcome. you can convert your RTF file to html.