# Reading file from SD card and loading it to WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-sdcard

i am trying to load a html file in webView from sd card its not working, Directory exists in SD card as well as file in it. Here is the code i have tried.

```
public void CheckReg()
    {
        File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "Reginfo/input/register.html" );
        if (file.exists())
        {
            index.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/Reginfo/input/register.html");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "File Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Reginfo/input/register.html");
    if (file.exists())
    {   
      index.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Reginfo/input/register.html");
```

dont forget to 
add permissions to menifest

Comment: the other part , checking the existence of file is also not working . . whats wrong with that...

Comment: thanks it worked :-) one more thing, i have jQuery Mobile JS and CSS file in assets/js folder of app how can i can their reference in register.html file which is on sd card and is downloaded after installing the application...?

Comment: post another question for tht with more information

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524714/accessing-application-asset-files-in-html-file

Answer (score 0):

should set like ,

```
 public void CheckReg()
 {


   File file = new File(Environment
                                         .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .getAbsolutePath()+"Reginfo/input/register.html" );
    if (file.exists())
    {
        index.loadUrl("file:///"+file);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "File Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't hard code the directory of the sdcard like that. Its typically at /mnt/sdcard/ but this is never assured instead of this you can write it like this.

and before you load the file from sd-card you make ensure that sd-card is mounted.

You can use the following:

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
} else {
    index.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Reginfo/input/register.html");
}
```