# Reference to local JS and CSS files inside local HTML file

Tags: android, webview

Lets take a look at this for example: [Loading existing .html file with android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview)
I load my HTML file but it contains references to other **local** css and js files. Do I need use the same file:/// URL inside the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your structure should be like this:

`/assets/html/index.html`

`/assets/scripts/index.js`

`/assets/css/index.css`

Then just do ( [Android WebView: handling orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes/27020832#27020832) )

```
    //in onCreate() for Activity, or in onCreateView() for Fragment
    if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null) { //this works only on single instance of webview, use a map with TAG if you need more
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
    }
```

Make sure you add

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Then just use urls

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zzzz</title>
    <script src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
```

EDIT:

That particular code will work only if you add the code that I linked

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment { //could be activity
    private enum WebViewStateHolder
    {
        INSTANCE;

        private Bundle bundle;

        public void saveWebViewState(WebView webView)
        {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            webView.saveState(bundle);
        }

        public Bundle getBundle()
        {
            return bundle;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.saveWebViewState(myWebView);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

As for whatever "security issue" you speak of, you didn't share enough data.

Comment: if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null) { //this works only on single instance of webview, use a map with TAG if you need more
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
    } doesnt work
and there seems to be a security issue with the reference inside the script. (cannot load file)

Comment: `there seems to be a security issue with the reference inside the script. (cannot load file)` I don't know what you mean.

Comment: It says file does not exist(the one in the reference)

Comment: then you should put it there, because apparently it's not there! I got this code from existing working code, therefore you're structuring something wrong. Is it in the `src\main\assets` folder?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rendering HTML in a WebView with custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css), you dont have to specify each CSS or JS. Include them in the HTML file itself.