# Load html file e.g "index.html" from internal storage to android webview

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, internal-storage

I want to load an html file with its folder containing images and .css files from the phones internal storage to an apps android-webview. i have tried a lot of examples from the net but nothing works.. i am new to android. i found and tried something like this

```
private String curURL = "file:///data/data/com.yourproject.example/files/index.html"; 
webview.loadUrl(curURL);
```

and many other more.
But i cannot find the path inside my phone "**com.yourproject.example**" even after i run the app and i have looked every folder inside because it is where i would suppose to put this folder "**files/index.html**" i assume. 
I know this is just easy for you guys but i am getting no luck in this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder assets and place you required files there. follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677730/5275639)

Comment: no i don't want my files to built with the app.  i want my files to be just in my device's internal storage and will be just called from there to the apps webview

Comment: Hi, did you have any updates on this question?
I have a similar problem. I want to download a zip with an html file, decompress it in the `data/data/cache` directory and use it.
The problem is that I can run the html file from the assets folder, but not from the `data/data/cache` directory (blank page is displayed).
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, in my case, I was extracting the files, but when accessing I was forgetting to pre append the `file://`. So for me, that was the solution. How about you? Have you solved your issue?