# Undesirable � character in webview

Tags: java, android, regex, webview

When I directly copy the content of my html file and store it in a string, then show it in webview using:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

everything is OK! I want to modify content of my html file (programmatically) before loading to webview, but when I read the html file from asset folder using below code

```
private String loadAssetTextAsString(Context context, String name) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        String str;
        boolean isFirst = true;
        while ( (str = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            if (isFirst)
                isFirst = false;
            else
                //buf.append('\n');
                buf.append(str);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error opening asset " + name);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error closing asset " + name);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

and then load it in webview, the webview unexpectedly shows � character (I think its name is soft hyphen). I have used UTF-8 as charset in my html file. Also I have used below code for removing � which failed.

```
myString = myString.replace("�", "");
```

How can I remove �? thanks for any help.

[image: � character]

Comment: You can directly open an HTML file in a WebView. Why do you need to read it into a String?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading existing .html file with android WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview)

Comment: That seems to be UTF-16BE encoding, needed for the InputStreamReader.

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 for your comment. I need to modify content of html before loading in webview.

Comment: Try `new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16")` as JoopEggen pointed out

Comment: Your problem is one of character encoding. Somewhere along the way (perhaps in the WebView) the bytes are decoded using a single-byte encoding, but the characters were actually encoded using a two-byte encoding.

Comment: Thank you @Floern.It worked. I had another question that why using myString.replace("�", "") doesnot remove �?

Comment: @iliailiaey ah, I just posted that as an answer ;)

Comment: @iliailiaey It doesn't remove the character, because your string does not actually contain that character. The encoding is simply displaying that character as "unknown"

Comment: @iliailiaey I expanded my answer about that, but it's just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content looks like it's encoded as UTF-16, where each character uses two bytes instead of one+ as in UTF-8.
Simple ASCII characters are prefixed with a null byte `\0` in UTF-16, which gets converted to a � when you try to display it.

Thus reading it as UTF-16 from the `InputStream` might solve the problem:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16"));
```

---

The `String.replace("�", "")` does not work because the � symbol as you see it is not the same as it's encoded in the String. Maybe directly replacing the null byte `\0` could work, if it's preserved during the decoding as UTF-8: `String.replace("\0", "")`.

Comment: Thank you @Floern. Your answer was very helpful for me.