# Android WebView for Facebook Like Button

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-like, webviewclient

I'm trying to make facebook like functionality in Android WebView (project specification does not allow browser opening, or any *out of application* activity).

So, restrictions are that it has to be done in WebView. I've managed to make it a dialog, and apon user's click like button, it (the WebView) redirects successfully (in the same view) to facebooks login page. After successful authentication, the `WebView` (in a dialog) is redirected to **blank page** with facebook header.

Interestingly enough, when user leaves the blank dialog and click again on the like button it works like perfectly (like and unlike) - it somehow keeps authentication active. To resolve the blank page, I've tried/used following:

- using `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverloadUrlForwarding` to keep whole process in same `WebView` dialog.
- using `WebChromeClient` to properly execute JavaScript - without it after login is not possible to like/unlike.
- tried using `setUserAgentString()` to simulate other browsers like Chrome or Firefox
- tried the SSL Error certificate handling (in API level 8) (at `WebViewClient`)

  `@Override
          public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
              handler.proceed();
          }`
- using (and all possible combination of these)

  `webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`
- Tried also persisting cookies with `CookieSyncManager`, `CookieManager` and manually handling.

All of this was with no result. I really appreciate **any** help!

Comment: Hi Can you please share you little code snippet for the mentioned functionaliy " I've managed to make it a dialog, and apon user's click like button, it (the WebView) redirects successfully "

Comment: Stefan can you please help me on this problem. I am facing an exact situation. My question is posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208427/facebook-like-button-redirecting-to-facebook-site-in-android

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get past the blank page you do this:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new LikeWebviewClient(this));

 private class LikeWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {        
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished url: " +url);
        // Facebook redirects to this url once a user has logged in, this is a blank page so we override this
        // http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?............
        if(url.startsWith("http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php")){
            String redirectUrl = getFacebookLikeUrl();
            view.loadUrl(redirectUrl);
            return;
        }
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  But there's another problem.  Normally the webview can save its state and not reload on orientation changes by making use of `webView.saveState()` and `webView.restoreState()`, but the solution presented here is kind of a 'double load' thing, and kind of defeats the orientation change save/restore state code.  Anyone have a solution/workaround?

Comment: To answer my question, I made use of `onConfigurationChanged()`.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes/2246555#2246555

Comment: @Blundell- Could you please tell me what getFacebookLikeUrl() returns: is it just the URL that the user intended to like?

Comment: @Abhijit Yeah it's just the facebook url from their API to 'like' a post.

Comment: could someone please post an example of what getFacebookLikeUrl() returns?  I'm totally stumped by what url this is meant to be or where one gets it.

Comment: @Blundell I am facing the exact situation. Trying hard to find a solution. Can you please help me understanding what is getFacebookLikeUrl() method? Is it a user defined one or from some library. I have posted a question on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208427/facebook-like-button-redirecting-to-facebook-site-in-android please help me.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar I can't really remember, but I defined it myself http://www.cantremember.com

Comment: @Blundell I didn't find that. Please share the specific uri

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my android application. The cause of the issue is FB login javascript opens a new page on a new window. Then it tries to close it after login success. Please follow flowing example from my working codes.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MyActivity" 
android:id="@+id/webview_frame">
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

The `Webview` of id "webview" is the main view for my content. Below is my activity codes.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/* URL saved to be loaded after fb login */
private static final String target_url="http://www.example.com";
private static final String target_url_prefix="www.example.com";
private Context mContext;
private WebView mWebview;
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private FrameLayout mContainer;
private long mLastBackPressTime = 0;
private Toast mToast;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_urimalo);
// final View controlsView =
// findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//mWebviewPop = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPop);
mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);

mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
}
private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
    //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
    if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) 
    {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
        // the page
        if(mWebviewPop!=null)
        {
            mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
            mWebviewPop=null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    if(host.equals("m.facebook.com"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
    // another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
        SslError error) {
    Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
    //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
}
}
class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
        boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
    mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
    mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
    Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
}
}
}
```

The key for this issue is `onCreateWindow`. A new window is created and inserted to the frame layout and removed upon success. I added the removal at `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work through this almost exact same problem on iPhone. What I had to do was to intercept the request that the webview makes to the 'blank page' you described above, and instead tell the webview to load the like URL.

Comment: how do you intercept a webview request and redirect it ?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't worked for me:(, but form observing i perceive that wrong redirected link started with

```
url.startsWith("http://m.facebook.com/a/profile.php?fan&id"))
```