# Facebook Like Button that Login with Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, single-sign-on

I embedded the like button as a `WebView` in my Android app.

I have logged-in to my Android app using the facebook-android-sdk via [SSO](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso); but when I clicked the like button, it still prompted the login page (of course it did).

I want to know if there's any way to let the `WebView` know that I've already logged-in (for example provide the `access_token` somewhere in the webpage)?

Thanks.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button

Comment: No, I've tried that solution. I want to use the "logged-in account" (the user has logged-in to my app) to "like", but if the "like button" is in an embedded `WebView`, the `WebView` will require the user to login again (within the `WebView`).

Comment: Did you try to add "the right" cookies into WebView for FB url? Maybe it can help. I'm now struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13210539/300581). In brief, you can't; but if you get the user to authenticate in the WebView once, you might be able to get the facebook auth cookie out of it and re-insert it into subsequent WebView instances.

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118