# Android webview facebook login error not logged in

Tags: android, facebook, webview, google-plus

I was trying to create an Android app with web view only to load a URL in which we want the user to login with Facebook, which is actually working fine in a normal android  browser. But in our app it show the error Not logged in. Please check screen shot[image]

And also my code

```
package com.kranti.bookclip;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

/**
 * Created by kranti-mac on 01/06/16.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected WebView mainWebView;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebview;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;

    private String url = "http://www.bookclip.com/#/";
    private String target_url_prefix = "www.bookclip.com/#/";


    public void onBackPressed(){

        if (mainWebView.isFocused() && mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mainWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Get main webview
        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //Progress Bar
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mainWebView, true);
        }

        //Cookie manager for the webview
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        //Get outer container
        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);

        //Settings
        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.bookclip.com/#/");

        mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
            //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
            if (host.equals(target_url_prefix))
            {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
                // the page
                if(mWebviewPop!=null)
                {
                    mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                    mWebviewPop=null;
                }
                return false;
            }

            if(host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com"))
            {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
//                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
            // another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
            Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
            //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }

    }

    private class MyCustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
    {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            if (progress == 100) {
                mProgress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
            mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
        }

    }

}
```

I already search a lot on web/ google search even I find this code online, but the problem is same. Thanks!

Comment: Part of the problem is that in Android, the webview and the browser does not share cookies, so the webview does not know the Facebook identity of the user. So you need to log the user in into the webview at least once.

Comment: Do you have the sample code for the same?

Comment: I faced a similar problem some time back. Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460116/facebook-like-button-opens-blank-page-in-android
and the linked questions. They maybe helpful.