# webview won't remember facebook login

Tags: android, webview, facebook-like

In my android app the user can like my facebook page. Therefore I use a webview that loads a webpage that contains a facebook like box. The page is loaded well into the webview and then the following happens:

1. WebView loads my webpage with a facebook like box
2. By clicking on the Like button the user is redirected to the facebook login page
3. After login the user is redirect again back to my custom like page
4. But when clicking the like button the user is again redirected to the facebook login page

So I would expect, that the like is possible after logging in. It seems somehow as if the webview does not remember the login. Therefore, what do I have to do to repair this.

The following screenshot sequence shows what's happening:
[image]

I want to avoid using the facebook sdk for android! Especially this procedure works very good in my iphone version of the app.

Here is some code that is used to implement my desired functionality:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView fbWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.facebookWebView );
        fbWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        fbWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("call url", url );
                if ( url.contains("login.php?skip_api_login") ) {
                    fbWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.de/iphone_facebook_like_page.html");
                    return null;
                }

                if( url.contains("user_successfully_liked") ) 
                    fbWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example-success.de");
                return null;
            }
        });

        fbWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.de/iphone_facebook_like_page.html");

    }
```

EDIT: I also tried the following to accept cookies but none of this worked

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        //rest is the same...
```

Overrding didn't work either

```
@Override  
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
      {  
        view.loadUrl(url);  
        return true;  
      }
```

Comment: Okay there is a thread on SO that solves the problem: [skip facebook blank page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have that error, because WebView isn't remembering cookies. Read that question on SO : [WebView and Cookies on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android)

Comment: I tried all the "solutions" offered in the thread an nothing worked. I updated my question show what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've gotten an answer to your problem, but I tried a combination of [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android) and the code below, and that worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
...
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true); // this last one is probably optional
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(<your url here>);
...
}
```

You will then need to call the corresponding methods for the CookieSyncManager singleton class as outlined in the link above. Note that the sync class is deprecated in API Level 21: [see details on CookieSyncManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html)