# Android WebView Facebook Login (popup/redirection issues)

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, redirect, webview

how is everyone?

I am working on a simple mobile application utilizing WebView. My website utilizes a layout giving it the appearance of a native app. I also allow users to login with their facebook account into my website. Here are my scenarios

** WORKS ** From PC/Chrome: Can access the mobile site URL, login with facebook which opens the pop-up dialog to either A.) Login, or B.) if user is FB logged in, prompt user to accept

** WORKS ** From Phone/Chrome: Can access the mobile site URL, login with facebook which opens a new tab with A.) Login, or B.) if user is FB logged in, prompt user to accept

** PROBLEM! ** From Phone/APK: Loads website in WebView, click login with facebook, opens facebook login page in the webview, but once I enter details and attempt to login, nothing happens. If I go to my home screen and reopen the app, it logs me in using the details I previously submitted

So basically what I am saying is that in the APP, once I leave my website URL and go to facebook's website to enter facebook details to login with it and press login -- it doesn't redirect back to my website for some reason. I've been plucking my hairs trying to find a solution to this, I've also searched extensively on here and other places but have not been able to find a workable solution, I'm sure many other people may be experiencing similar issues with facebook or other services

Here is my code (was originally much more simple, however I am now utilizing what I found in another topic covering this issue, however it still does not work -- I'd also like to mention that with this portion of code that I found, when TARGET_URL is loaded from a phone, the phone will redirect it to the mobile version of the website, which, since it's how the code functions, causes it to open up in a browser instead of my WebView)

I'm totally confused =/

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* URL saved to be loaded after fb login */
private static final String target_url="http://www.moneygirlsmusic.tv/app/index.php?do=/mobile/";
private static final String target_url_prefix="www.moneygirlsmusic.tv/app/index.php?do=/mobile/";
private Context mContext;
private WebView mWebview;
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private FrameLayout mContainer;
private long mLastBackPressTime = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // final View controlsView =
    // findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //mWebviewPop = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPop);
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
    mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);

    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

}


private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) 
        {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if(mWebviewPop!=null)
            {
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com"))
        {

            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
     startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
            SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }

}
```

I forgot to include my previous resources used to try to figure this out

- Making facebook login work with an Android Webview
  [Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview)
- Android WebView for Facebook Like Button

  ### [Android WebView for Facebook Like Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button)

Comment: You said: "but once I enter details and attempt to login, nothing happens.". What do you mean by 'nothing happens'? Do you get a blank, white screen?

Answer (score 0):

In android 6 running in some mobiles you should add this to your java code to redirect . otherwise it doesn't redirect and nothing happens .

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     return false;
 }
```

});