# Android + Flash screen rotation problem

Tags: android

I am using this code to show a flash video, My problem is when I go from vertical to horizontal position, application reloads and video is reset. How can i avoid this. Please advice

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.internalwebview);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

            mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I found the answer by my self.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<android:label="@string/app_name"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

This will disable the auto-orientation-change otherwise you will had to handle the change yourself

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you could try saving the state of your WebView when the orientation changes by adding a reference to `onSaveInstanceState()` in your activity:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Then resetting it again in your `onCreate()` method, as follows:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.internalwebview);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
 }
```

Although I'm not quite sure if it works for embedded Flash video as well.
See for more information [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes) or the [Android SDK reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges)

Comment: great explanation, but just in case one wonders what happens when an orientation change occurs ... [here's a good breakdown](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/26/android-lifecycle-triggers-part-2/)