# Alternatives to WebView.savePicture() for saving display data

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to get a `WebView` to stop reloading the page when the device's orientation changes.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes/2700865#2700865), I was looking at [`WebView.saveState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29).  The documentation for this method says:

> Please note that this method no longer restores the display data for this WebView. See `savePicture(Bundle, File)` and `restorePicture(Bundle, File)` for saving and restoring the display data.

But when I looked at [`savePicture()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#savePicture%28android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File%29), I found that it's been deprecated:

> **This method is deprecated.**
>   This method is now obsolete.

In that case, what methods should developers be using to save and restore the display data?

Comment: Does locking the orientation have no difference to you?

Comment: @iturki I would prefer to support all orientations, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: Ok. did you try to use saveState() and restoreState() ?

Comment: @iturki Yes, but the WebView turns blank for a second after an orientation change.  That's why I was interested in saving the display data.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add this config line to your activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyWebViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

Comment: Since the use of `configChanges` is somewhat [controversial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), I wanted to try using `saveState()`.  This does not answer the question I was asking.

Comment: What's controversial about it? The first line of that link clearly states that if you don't need to apply any changes during a specific configuration change and it's a performance hit to rebuild the Activity (in your case, reloading a website), then this prevents the activity from being rebuilt. It's only not recommended if you need to use different resources during a certain configuration change. Anywhere in your Activity, are you using different resources based on the orientation?

Comment: And even if it were case that you used different resources based on the orientation, you could still easily handle it by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method. In your case, there's no reason why your activity needs to be destroyed and reinitialized all because the orientation changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem but had to make a couple of additions to get it to work with various version (including ICS).

In the main app activity I added a slightly different version of what Jason offered.

```
<activity
android:name=".MyMainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

I had this working on pre-Honeycomb with:

```
           <activity
        ....
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        .... >
```

I had to make the first example to get it running on all versions.  I'm currently using fragments and ActionBarSherlock for backwards compatibility.

Hope this helps.