# WebView content not fitting within WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

- > As you can see the image the pink color background is my WebView > and I am displaying html pages in that WebView but the complete page
  >   is not fitting within the WebView i.e having scroll bar in case of > landscape mode, please suggest me what should I do? I want that the > complete page should show in WebView without scrollbar.here the image of WebView is

[image]

Comment: that is two lengthy but here i am telling xml structure is-            <Relative layout><TwoDscrollview><Webview></webview></TwoDscrollview></Relativelayout>

Comment: when you come portrait to landscap Webview is realoded???

Comment: yes i am reloading the page because every time on onCreate() i am tring to fit the content within webview

Comment: so your problem is noting.. onConfiguration Changing..http://stackoverflow.com/a/2246555/1339473 and also update..mainfest

Comment: updated but no effect after that also

Comment: suppose user directly run in landscape so this issue will come and by the way that previous suggestion is not working