# Android Studio WebView landscape filled?

Tags: java, android, layout, webview, landscape

I'am trying to display a mjpeg video (from ip cam) in a web view and i want to fit the webview content 100% correct to the screen. Work great in portrait mode but in landscape i can still scroll up and down.

Any suggestions?

```
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.loadUrl(StreamURL);
```

Greets

Comment: You should handle the onConfigurationChange per your own, have you read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419735/webview-not-re-sizing-properly-on-orientation-change)?

Comment: The app should only run in landscape. Portrait is disabled

Comment: You want to make it like "[Scaling Image to fit the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395292/android-webview-scaling-image-to-fit-the-screen)"?

Comment: Already tryed that and i'm still able to scroll up and down after that