# Android WebView - Resize after orientation without reload the page

Tags: android, android-webview, android-orientation

I have a webview with `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"` on the AndroidManifest.xml file because i don't want to reload the page when i'm changing the orienatation.

There are some pages when i'm changing from portrait to landscape and then from lanscape to portrait the page takes only half of the webview.

How can i fix it? I don't want to reload the page again.
There is any way to resize the content without reload the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView handling orientation changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes)

Comment: not clear. You put android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ans still it is loading ?

Comment: yes. It still half of the screen.

Comment: have you already found a solution? the same issue

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"    
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and yet if you cannot get solution then there is something wrong in you code becuse you can chek my application it's working fine in my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accusol.zipbooks&hl=en

Comment: I will try the "android:windowSoftInputMode" but screenSize is available only from API11. I need from API8.

Comment: you can set minsdk=8 & targetSdk=11 so you can get it

Comment: Thanx, it works for me! I'm using android:minSdkVersion="11", android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in same problem, but at last found out the reason is related with "viewport" tag in the html file, not code. 
Try add this:
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`
in the html file
and see whether the problem still exists.
Gluck.

Answer (score -1):

Use  screenSize also

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Screen size is only available from api11. I need it from api8.

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" not working. Still half of screen.