# How to save Login Information on WebView Application?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, savestate

I am Working on an Android application that uses webView to load a web page. The webpage which I am using has a Login form I can log in using that form and do my stuff. The problem is when I close the app (exit it) and open the application I've to do Login again. How can I save the Login information such that when I open my app I don't have to do Login?

Is there any way to save all information before closing the Application?

Comment: Overwrite  onPause and onResume methods like done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832845/webview-is-not-restoring-the-state-after-it-was-killed-by-the-user

Comment: Thanks It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first register the JavaScriptInterface on your webview. JavaScriptInterFace can be a inner class as shown below. This class will have a function that you can call from html page( via javaScript ) and inside this function you can write code to change activity.

Here is the working solution for you:

```
public class JavascriptInterfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    WebView wv;

    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // register class containing methods to be exposed to JavaScript

        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface"); 

       if(not_logged_in){
         wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");
       }


    }


    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void login_success()
        {
            // save login success.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the html page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{
JSInterface.login_success();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for Help :)

Comment: @ShantanuPatil if it is helpfull.. then accept it as answer.