# Android WebView Save Display State when app closes

Tags: javascript, android, webview, save, android-webview

I want to be able to save the state of a WebView when a user closes out of my app and be able to restore it to exactly how it was when the user returns to the app. I want it to restore websites with forms, online calculators that store the history of calculations, or any websites that make Javascript objects dynamically. How can I do this?
Below are some of the methods I have tried.

I have tried using the saveState method found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) but the behavior has been changed.

> Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView.

I want to be able to restore the display data.

I have tried the saveWebArchive method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) but when saving and restore a web archive version it doesn’t put the display data back exactly how it was.

I am not able to use any of the HTML5 storage methods or `evaluateJavascript` to handle this since I want to be able to save and restore the state for any website I visit.

Comment: Hi, i was thinking of "user closes out of my app", does this meant that app is being totally close from app manager (square or overview button)? if yes, i think it is not possible, since webview is being destroy the time app was closed.

Comment: Hello, "Close out of my app" means app go to background, . So when you go back to your application the onResume method will be called instead of onCreate. So put your code on OnResume.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479519/how-to-save-restore-webview-state ... how would you do this with Chrome or Puppeteer? Also, that concept doesn't consider that forms or access tokens may long have timed out on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the application to the background, it is enough to load the URL once only:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        webView.loadUrl(defaultUrl);
    }
}
```

But when terminating the application, the restore capabilities are rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

You could using this code in your custom WebView:

```
override fun onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility: Int) {
        if (visibility != View.GONE) super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(View.VISIBLE)
}
```