# How to play video fullscreen with landscape in Android WebView?

Tags: android, html, video, webview

1. I want to play video fullscreen in Android `WebView`, so I use HTML5 tag `<video>` and put these web files into *src/main/asset/...* folder.
2. But when I clcik 'Fullscreen' button, the video just moving to center in the vertical direction(portrait).
3. So, my question is how to set fullscreen in landscape? Thank you.
   [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)

Comment: I have tried that way, but it did not work. @petey

Answer (score 2):

I used [cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) and [RotatedVerticalFrameLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40279836/6038626). I just changed part of onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)  in VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.

```
 // Hide the non-video view, add the video view, and show it
 activityNonVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 Point screenSize = Utils.getDisplaySize(activityNonVideoView.getContext());
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(screenSize.y, screenSize.x);
 params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
 videoViewContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
 activityVideoView.addView(videoViewContainer);
 activityVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In Activity I changed line in OnToggledFullscreenCallback

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)
```

to

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

so that it hides navigation bar.

For getting display size I used

```
public static Point getDisplaySize(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    return size;
}
```